# Unable to calculate Percentage in thread to update status.

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I'm processing bunch of files using multiple threads.All of them updates number of file processed by updating a global variable:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&my_lock);
prec++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_lock);
```

And there is another thread which is showing status of number of file processed:

```
while(1)
{
  printf("\r%d %.2f percent files Pre-Processed......",prec,(float)(prec/560)*100);
 fflush(stdout);
 if(prec==560)
   {
        e=1;
        break;  
    }      
}
```

Why am i always seeing percentage part as 0.00 ?
Also, the program is exiting without complete execution, with no error/warning, any idea why ?

Comment: You could float prec before dividing it.  As elsewhere... the code as given doesn't show how you ensure the value of prec is valid at the point you print it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should lock mutex for reading a global variable(`prec`).

```c
while(1)
{
  int curr_prec;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&my_lock);
  curr_prec = prec;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_lock); 

  printf("\r%d %.2f percent files Pre-Processed......",
    curr_prec, (float)(curr_prec/560)*100);
  fflush(stdout);
  if(prec==560)
  {
    e=1;
    break;
  }
}
```